How to choose a PhD research area in AI to prepare for industry roles?
I’m planning to pursue a PhD in Artificial Intelligence to transition into industry after graduation, rather than stay in academia. I’m having difficulty choosing a research area that will set me up for the industry, especially since AI research evolves quickly. Here are my specific questions:

Should I prioritize choosing a topic that is currently relevant to
companies, or is it better to focus on one that might become
important in the next three years?
Will focusing on a specific PhD topic limit my opportunities to work
in other areas, or do companies in AI value transferable skills
across different topics?

I am interested in many areas of AI, and I’m finding it difficult to choose a topic to work on. What are the factors that I should consider when selecting a research topic?

What part of the world are you in? "Industrial PhD" probably means different things in different places.

I second @cag51's question. "Industrial Ph.D." could mean a Ph.D. you do "on the side" while working in industry. But the rest of your question rather suggests a "traditional" Ph.D. with the aim of moving into industry afterwards. Please clarify.

Re your substantive question: I don't know whether this is a good fit for our site, being quite opinion-dependent. IMO (you see?) the limiting factor to your employment as a Ph.D. will less be your specific topic, but whether an employer has headcount available. Ph.D.s will be expected to be flexible enough to work on quite different topics. And nobody knows today what will be hot in three years. Few people had GenAI on their radar three years before ChatGPT became a craze. And if you do GenAI today, there are good chances the bubble will burst in the next three years.

I am in Europe. By "industrial PhD," I mean a program where a student works closely with a company, often on applied research that directly impacts the company’s interests while being enrolled in a university's PhD program. The Industrial PhD is funded by the company. This contrasts with a traditional PhD which is usually more focused on theoretical research. within the university setting.

Yes the other questions 1,3 and 4 are related to the "traditional PhD"

We usually advise one question per post. I downselected one of your questions -- feel free to post it separately. I'll leave the other two since they seem to go together.


Should I prioritize choosing a topic that is currently relevant to companies, or is it better to focus on one that might become important in the next three years?

It is very difficult to predict what might happen in the future. Both the science and the "industry" of AI are changing rapidly. Three years ago, applying deep learning to text summarization, translation, or question-answering might have seemed like a good idea. But as it turns out, the majority of such work is now obsolete in the face of Chat-GPT. Similarly, industry's demand for customized chat bots is way higher than we could have predicted years ago; now that they actually work, everyone wants one.
Given this, I wouldn't try to game the system. Focus on whatever topic you find interesting. Learn the fundamentals; don't just become a technician who knows how to type model.train(). But do also take the time to focus on skills such as programming, technical writing, and statistics. R&D positions in ML are fairly easy to find (at least relative to other fields), but most will require you to actually implement prototypes and do experiments; it is usually not enough to do theoretical analysis only.

Will focusing on a specific PhD topic limit my opportunities to work in other areas, or do companies in AI value transferable skills across different topics?

Your mileage will vary. Historically, companies have been very open to hiring smart people and teaching them how to do ML. Someone who actually had a degree in ML -- let alone in a relevant type of ML -- was a unicorn who could write their own ticket. But the past (or even present) is not necessarily a good predictor of the future: these days, more universities are offering degrees in ML, more people are taking such degrees, and some areas are cooling now that the low-hanging fruit has been exhausted. That said, smart people with relevant skills tend to land on their feet, so even if getting the exact job you want proves difficult, it's unlikely you will starve.

I think this is good, but it's missing two pieces of relevant advice I'd recommend: (1) Go look at current job postings for jobs you'd like after graduating, and try to synthesize their "checklist" requirements. Experience with certain broad frameworks (think PyTorch) are often filters. Publications in certain conferences are increasingly common as filters for ML related positions. You can work this kind of training gracefully into the other aspects of a degree. (2) Ask as many experienced people as you can what they think the "core skill set" is for further data.

@user176372, actually, your point 1 won't work in a fast changing field as the writer here points out. Today's jobs can be obsolete by the end of a doctorate.

@Buffy I disagree: There are core skills which have not really shifted that much over a 5 year time frame. You can re-do this check 2 years into a program or whatever if you're particularly jumpy. The people looking for NeurIPS/ICML/etc. papers for their AI hires are unlikely to turn up their nose at those in a few years' time frame.

Thanks for the answers. What I see in research positions like Deep Mind or Meta research labs is the requirement to publish on top conferences NeurIPS/ICML/CVPR. I don't know if I will able to publish there, but it seems the only common requirement, or am I wrong?
